# Left Outer join with Linq without DefaultIfEmpty

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to use this [sample](http://www.devcurry.com/2011/01/linq-left-join-example-in-c.html):

What I want is the ONLY return of:´the Book with Id = 2.

```
 new Book{BookID=2, BookNm=".NET and COM for Newbies"},
```

I want only those book(s) which has no Orders.

When I remove the DefaultIfEmpty() it does not work either.

**UPDATE**

```
 Person magnus = new Person { FirstName = "Magnus", LastName = "Hedlund" };
            Person terry = new Person { FirstName = "Terry", LastName = "Adams" };
            Person charlotte = new Person { FirstName = "Charlotte", LastName = "Weiss" };
            Person arlene = new Person { FirstName = "Arlene", LastName = "Huff" };

            Pet barley = new Pet { Name = "Barley", Owner = terry };
            Pet boots = new Pet { Name = "Boots", Owner = terry };
            Pet whiskers = new Pet { Name = "Whiskers", Owner = charlotte };
            Pet bluemoon = new Pet { Name = "Blue Moon", Owner = terry };
            Pet daisy = new Pet { Name = "Daisy", Owner = magnus };

            // Create two lists.
            List<Person> people = new List<Person> { magnus, terry, charlotte, arlene };
            List<Pet> pets = new List<Pet> { barley, boots, whiskers, bluemoon, daisy };

            var query = from person in people
                        join pet in pets on person equals pet.Owner into gj                       
                        where !gj.Any()
                        select person;
```

I just tried this code and it seems it works!

I get returned the person Arlene she has no pets!

Can somene confirm that this is a known approach? I just invented it LOL

Comment: Its the same code from the link I pasted... In my opinion this link offers no real left join. I just want to return the books without orders.

Comment: hahhaaa....it's a general approach...you didn't invent anything new :D

Comment: @PranavPatel I havent found any link about this approach always only this DefaultIfEmpty stuff!

Comment: @Elisabeth.....are you serious about this funny joke...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misinterpreting how left join works. `a LEFT JOIN b` will return all items from `a`, regardless if they have matching items in `b`. If I correctly understand your question, you don't need a join here at all, because you don't want any additional data from `bookOrders`. You can just use LINQ's `All` extension method:

```
var query = bookList.Where(b => bookOrders.All(o => o.BookId != b.BookId).ToList();
```

This will return all books for which no book order contains the book's ID. I'm basing the names on the linked article.

Comment: yes about the left join works I was wrong, but you were right.